# How to consume RESTFul webservice using HTTP POST in .net 2.0

Tags: c#, .net

I need to consume a restful webservice using .net 2.0 framework and not by using WCF. The RESTFul service is built in java and is designed only for POST operations. To consume the webservice in winforms in .net I am using a `WebClient` object.

Below is the sample code

```
string data="some data";

string url="some uri";

WebClient request = new WebClient();

//Application throws internal server error 500 at runtime when it hits this line.
string results = request.UploadString(url, "POST", data);
```

Is there anything wrong that i am doing here ? any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the service method in question accepts plain-text data and not something structured like JSON or XML/SOAP?

Comment: Yes the service is expecting the data in a plain-text format like "applicationName=ABC" and NOT like JSON or XML.

Answer (score 0):

"**Internal Server Error**" is an indication that the Server has difficulty in processing the String you uploaded. There could be various causes to "**Internal Server Error**". Do you have access to the Server side code for debugging? One thing I can think of is the Encoding of the String you uploaded. You can probably try to set the [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.encoding%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property of WebClient to something else.